# Best practices on multiple SQL calls to avoid repeated results

Tags: sql, sqlite, pdo

Should multiple SQL calls be used when it can be done in one call, if the one call returns repeated data?

Like say, and this is a really oversimplified version of what I'm trying to do, we want to get a user info and their favorite bands.  If I did it in one call, I could do:

```
SELECT userName, userAge, userGender, bandName FROM users NATURAL JOIN userBands NATURAL JOIN bands WHERE userID = 47
```

That will return to me a list of all the bands that user likes, but with every single one it will return the user name, age, and gender.

I could do two calls…

```
SELECT userName, userAge, userGender FROM users WHERE userID = 47
SELECT bandName FROM userBands NATURAL JOIN bands WHERE userID = 47
```

where the first just returns the basic info once, and the second just returns the list of bands.  Is there any best practice with this?  Is there another way to approach this that I'm not realizing?   And what if (as it will be in my my real-world case) that it's not just two calls to separate the data, but 4 or 5?  So it's a lot more calls, but it's also a lot more extraneous data returned to do it in one call.

I'm using PHP PDO if that makes a difference in the answer.

Comment: There's per-call overhead, you generally want to minimize this. So you should generally combine related calls whenever it makes sense to do so.

Comment: It seems you miss a **GROUP BY**, in the first query...

Comment: You should avoid `NATURAL JOIN`, because it's going to end up comparing two columns you really don't expect.  This is especially prevalent in major production dbs, which tend to have audit columns (like `inserted_at` timestamps) which aren't comparable in many situations (especially if columns aren't prefixed with table-names - doing so is considered to be noise in most cases).  Why are you storing age, as it's a derived value?

Comment: What will you do with the results?

Comment: The SQL query I provided above is just simplified/made-up column names and such because I didn't want to distract people with the more complex calls I am doing.  Though I am doing NATURAL JOIN as I built the database with columns specifically named for the purposes of using NATURAL JOIN.

Answer (score 1):

There is another answer, which is to combine the bands into a single column using `group_concat()`:

```
SELECT u.userName, u.userAge, u.userGender, group_concat(b.bandName)
FROM users u NATURAL JOIN
     userBands ub NATURAL JOIN
     bands b
WHERE userID = 47
GROUP BY u.userName, u.userAge, u.userGender;
```

This gives you one row per user with the list of bands.

By the way, I would discourage you from using `NATURAL JOIN`.  The query then depends on the metadata for the join keys -- and a small change to the table structures could have a big impact on lots of queries.  Use either an explicit `on` clause or a `using` clause.

Comment: Cool, I will try this later tonight.  And I use NATURAL JOIN because I built the database with columns specifically named for the purposes of using NATURAL JOIN. :-)

Comment: Hmm, I just tried it.  group_concat() is a bit of a hack but I think it's the best solution presented for the question I asked.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This makes sense when sending data across a network to a remote user. Why waste bandwidth sending the same data over and over again? For that purpose, a good method is to place the the data in some sort of XML structure.

```
<users>
  <user>
    <userdata1>...</userdata1>
    <...>...</...>
    <bands>
      <band>...</band>
      <band>...</band>
      ...
    </bands>
  </user>
</users>
```

No duplicated data is sent. Whether you form this structure from a single result set with the duplicated data or from the two result sets is up to you and your team. Play around with both and decide which is best under your specific situation.

Comment: Is there a way to get SQLite to return the data in XML?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17908023/can-i-generate-xml-data-from-the-sqlite-database

Comment: So… I guess that's "no".